# Comparing two partition's data in hive

Tags: hive, hql, md5

I have 9 million records in each of my partition in hive and I have two partitions. The table has 20 columns. Now I want to compare the dataset between the partitions based upon an id column. which is the best way to do it considering the fact that self join with 9 million records will create performence issues.

Comment: Do you have the same ids in both partitions? And I don't thing self join with 9m records is ans issue for Hive...

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the SMB join - its mostly like a merging two sorted lists. However in this case you will need to create two more tables.

Another option would be to write an UDF to do the same - that would be project by itself. The first option is easier.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the self join and have it fail? I don't think it should be an issue as long as you specify the join condition correctly. 9 million rows is actually not that much for Hive. It can handle large joins by using the join condition as a reduce key, so it doesn't actually do the full cartesian product.

```
select a.foo, b.foo
from my_table a
full outer join my_table b
on a.id <=> b.id
where a.partition = 'x' and b.partition = 'y'
```

Answer (score 0):

To do a full comparison of 2 tables (or comparing 2 partitions of the same table), my experience has shown me that using some checksum mechanism is a more effective and reliable solution than Joining the tables (which gives performance problems as you mentioned, and also gives some difficulties when keys are repeated for instance).

You could have a look at this Python program that handles such comparisons of Hive tables (comparing all the rows and all the columns), and would show you in a webpage the differences that might appear: https://github.com/bolcom/hive_compared_bq.

In your case, you would use that program specifying that the "2 tables to compare" are the same and using the "--source-where" and "--destination-where" to indicate which partitions you want to compare. The "--group-by-column" option might also be useful to specify the "id" column.